# Regex to pull sub-path

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df with a place field containing strings that looks like so:

```
countryName0 / provinceName0 / countyName0 / cityName0
countryName1 / provinceName1
```

Using this code I can pull out the finest resolution place identifier:

```
df$shortplace <- trimws(basename(df$place))
```

or:

```
df$shortplace <- gsub(".*/ ", "", df$place)
```

e.g.

```
cityName0
provinceName1
```

I can then use ggmap library to extract geocodes for cityName0 and provinceName1:

```
df$geo <- geocode(df$shortplace)
```

Result looks like this:

```
geo.lat   geo.long
-33.789    147.909
-29.333    133.819
```

Unfortunately, some city names are not unique e.g. Perth is the capital of Western Australia, a town in Tasmania, and a city in Scotland. What I need to do is extract not the place identifier after the last "/" but the second last "/" (and replace the "/" with a " " to provide more information for the geocode() function. How do I scan to second last "/" and extract highest and second highest order place names? E.g.

```
                shortplace
     countyName0 cityName0
countryName1 provinceName1
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: By using your code, i get `[1] "cityName0"     "provinceName1"` what is the expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways, but `strsplit()` seems the most straightforward to me here. Give this a try:

```
x = "countryName0 / provinceName0 / countyName0 / cityName0"
x_split = strsplit(x, " / ")[[1]] # Somewhat confusingly, result of strsplit() is a list; [[1]] pulls out the one and only entry here
n_terms = length(x_split)
result = paste(x_split[n_terms - 1], x_split[n_terms], sep = ", ")
result
# [1] "countyName0, cityName0"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is `sub` to match the alpha numeric characters followed by one or more spaces, `/` followed by space (`\\s+`), then another set of alpha numeric characters until the end of the string (`$`), capture as a group and replace with the backreferences (`\\1 \\2`) of the capture groups

```
df$shortplace <- sub(".*\\b([[:alnum:]]+)\\s+\\/\\s+([[:alnum:]]+)$", "\\1 \\2", df$place)
df$shortplace
#[1] "countyName0 cityName0"      "countryName1 provinceName1"
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Using the regex101 online regex editor, this python expression finds the last two names. ((?:/[^/\r\n]*){2})$. The R syntax may be different. What I do not know how to do is paste what it finds.

Comment: @user2995175  It is based on your example and it is working fine with me

Comment: Thanks. Probably my data example is not 100% the same as my actual data. Appreciate your help!

Comment: OK this is my problem: place <-  "Phu Yen / Tuy An / An Chan / Phu Phong" , df <- data.frame(place), df$shortplace <- sub(".*\\b([[:alnum:]]+)\\s+\\/\\s+([[:alnum:]]+)$", "\\1 \\2", df$place), result subs whole string i.e.                                    place                             shortplace
1 Phu Yen / Tuy An / An Chan / Phu Phong Phu Yen / Tuy An / An Chan / Phu Phong

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the end:

```
df$shortplace <- gsub("((?:/[^/\r\n]*){2})$", "\1", df$place)
df$shortplace <- gsub("\\ / ", ", ", df$place)
```

Not super elegant but it does the job.